# How to generate a lead time report in JIRA without a plugin?

Tags: jira, reporting

Has anyone compiled a lead time report (in any format) from JIRA without the use of a plug-in?

If so, how did you do it?

The native Control Chart tracks cycle time but not individual times for statuses or columns.  I found some documentation from JIRA but it is several years old.

If the only option is to export to XLS and interrogate the data then I am happy with that but would prefer a native solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the 'out of the box' solution Jira offers is the 'Control chart'.

The alternative for this would be to have [custom calculated fields](https://innovalog.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JMCF/overview).